# How to detect if a user join in anyone of voice channel?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I would simply like that when a specific user enters any voice chat on my discord server, my bot will detect it and then go into voice and say "x user joined the chat or something like this" (I already know how). The question is how to detect the user entering? (Detection must be instant).
I tried to using this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(message, after, before, member):
ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
u = ctx.guild.get_member(428938023057620994)
for channel in ctx.guild.voice_channels:
    if sebastiano in channel:
        tts = gTTS(text=u + "in voice chat", lang='en')
        tts.save("u.mp3")
        try:
            vc = await channel.connect()
            await vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('sebastiano.mp3'))
            await vc.disconnect()
        except:
            await ctx.send("Scusate ho la 104 e non funziono.")
```

But doesn't work:

> File "/home/diego/Documents/Python 3/CancerBot/cancerbot.py", line 26, in on_voice_state_update
> ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
> File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 880, in get_context
> view = StringView(message.content)
> AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'content'

Answer (score 1):

you have some problems here:

there is no message or ctx in an on_voice_state_update.

the parameters have to be as [follow](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update):

[member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member) - the member who joined/left/moved channel

[before](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20voicestate#discord.VoiceState) - the voice state before. if he had entered a channel and didn't move from one channel to another, the channel attribute would be None

[after](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20voicestate#discord.VoiceState) - the voice state after. if he left a channel and didn't move channels the channel attribute would be None

you answer your question to check if someone has joined I would do it also if he moved I would do:

```py
if after.channel:
```

then do what you've wanted